# AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, enums, javabeans

i have an enum as below:

```
public enum UserRole {
    ADMIN,ORGANIZER,USER
}
```

and then in another class, i am trying to make a collection of this enum:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @OneToMany
    Collection<UserRole> userRole;

}
```

But it complains with below error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.eventer.demo.model.User.userRole[com.eventer.demo.model.UserRole]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use @OneToMany on non entity classes. You should use @ElementCollection instead which can be used on String, Integer, Enum and other basic types that don’t have a primary key.

Answer (score 4):

You must use @ElementCollection because , This User Role  is enum  and it is not included in database.  JPA 2.0 makes the latter case simple with @ElementCollection:

> JPA 2.0 defines an ElementCollection mapping. It is meant to handle
>   several non-standard relationship mappings. An ElementCollection can
>   be used to define a one-to-many relationship to an Embeddable object,
>   or a Basic value (such as a collection of Strings). An
>   ElementCollection can also be used in combination with a Map to define
>   relationships where the key can be any type of object, and the value
>   is an Embeddable object or a Basic value.

```
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=UserRole.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "USER_ROLE",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    @Column(name="ROLE")
    Collection<UserRole> roles;
```